# Is it possible to use Kafka Connect to mirror an RDBMS table to a Kafka Stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I know it's possible to push updates from a database to a Kafka stream using Kafka Connect. My question is, can I create a consumer to write changes from that same stream back into the table without creating an infinite loop?

I'm assuming if I create a consumer that writes updates into the database table, it would trigger Connect to push that update to the stream, etc. Is there a way around this so I can mirror a database table to a stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stream from a Kafka topic to a database using the [JDBC Sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html) for Kafka Connect.

You'd need to code in your business logic for avoiding an infinite replication loop into either the connectors or your consumer. For example:

- JDBC Source connector uses a `WHERE` clause to only pull records with a flag set to indicate they are the original record
- Custom Single Message Transform in the source connector to drop records with a flag set to indicate they are not the original record
- Stream application (e.g. KSQL / Kafka Streams) processes the inbound stream of all database changes to filter out only those with a flag set to indicate they are the original record

  - Inefficient because then you're still streaming everything from the database

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It is possible to configure synchronisation/replication.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure about the terminology. Is there some documentation I can read with more information on this?